# Symfony 3 dont find pdo_mysql driver

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

My symfony project do not find pdo_mysql driver. I am using debian server. The same config works on OSX ok but not here. When I use php -m command it show driver and also the php -i |grep pdo_mysql show:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
pdo_mysql
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock =>     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

This is my symfony configuration and paramters:

```
parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 3306
database_name: bisol_time
database_user: root
database_password: root
```

Config:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
```

So what can i do. I try everything and read every topic under this problem but i do not find the solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I find out thet it is a problem only with php 7. I install php 5 and the same configuration and it works. Anyone know why and how to do it in php 7?

Comment: Maybe because of different configs for CLI and webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to the Symfony but for the system setup.

As you can see when you run PHP in CLI it uses the config from `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini` (notice the **cli** in the path). While when used by Apache it uses most likely `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini` or similar.

You can either nevigate to `/etc/php/7.0/` or create `info.php` with `<?php phpinfo();` and see where the config files are.

It seems that in that PHP configuration for apache the driver is not installed.

Comment: Yes, I figure it out when I change the version of php that it is not symfony problem, but php configuration. I created simple php script using PDO to connect to database and it worked, but it did not work on SF project. This is why I suspect that is maybe somting with SF too? Alse i used php -i |grep ini to locate all config files and find the one with pdo_mysql it is /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini and inside is only extension=pdo_mysql.so and commnted priority.

Comment: it would be nice if you can accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a different pdo for PHP 5.
On my system (CentOS 6) I have `php70u-pdo.i686`. I checked by using `yum list installed |grep pdo`. I can't guide you to install on OSX, I suspect you need to use `brew`, but check to see if you can install pdo for PHP7 and enable it in your php.ini file.

That sounds like the problem.

---

**EDIT # 2 Based on Comments**

Can you try:

```
apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mysql
```

I think the mysql installs pdo as well. Try it. not sure if it will work.

Comment: No on OSX is no problem I done it already. The problem is on Debian server (my production server, OSX is my development machine personal computer) I solve the problem by uninstaling php7 from debian server and instaling php5. It works now, but i wolud like to know why so in the future when I will use php 7 that the app will work ok. And btw on osx i used brew yes. tnx